# How to exceed the Sharepoint 5000 threshold in Rest-API Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I can't use Office365-REST-Python-Client to retrieve Sharepoint files because it's only works on Windows not on  Linux - Docker (it throws error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/saml_token_provider.py", line 102, in get_authentication_cookie
logger.error(e.response.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text')

The type of authentication (either app client or user credentials) doesn't have parameter for me to add token manually.

I'm trying to retrieve the items via standard REST API but I don't know how to retrieve all rows (150+k rows). Is it possible to do it without JScript? I only want to retrieve files that have properties "Approved". But I don't know how to integrate CAML Query with REST API. I tried to use filter, but because of the 5000 max threshold, it didn't give me the result at all.

Any help is much appreciated.